# Laravel: concat multiple model queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have two method's in the `User` class that return different queries. I would like to use both like this

```
$users = User::fromCountry('DE')
                    ->isMaster()
                    ->paginate(20);
```

but it is not working, since `isMaster()` is a method from `User` and not from the query builder:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isMaster()

I also tried

```
$users = User::fromCountry('DE')
                    ->(User::isMaster())
                    ->paginate(20);
```

but this is also not working. Is it possible to easily combine my queries from the `User` class?

---

Just in case its necessary, here are the two methods from the `User` class:

```
public static function isMaster()
    {
      switch (orga) {
        case 1:
          return static::where('modeIN','=','MT');

        case 2:
          return static::where('modeICI','=','CMT');

        case 3:
          return static::where('modeWHO','=','HMT');
      }
    }


    public static function fromCountry($country)
    {
      return static::where(
              function($query) use($country){
                $query->whereHas('addresses',
                          function($q) use($country){
                            $q->where('idCountry','=',$country);
                          }
                        )
                      ->orWhereHas('institutes',
                        function($q) use($country){
                          $q->whereHas('addresses',
                            function($q) use($country){
                              $q->where('idCountry','=',$country);
                            });
                        }
                      );
             });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your modal function to:

```
public function scopeIsMaster($query)
    {
      switch (orga) {
        case 1:
          return $query->where('modeIN','=','MT');

        case 2:
          return $query->where('modeICI','=','CMT');

        case 3:
          return $query->where('modeWHO','=','HMT');
      }
    }

public function scopeFromCountry($query,$country)
    {
      return $query->where(
              function($query) use($country){
                $query->whereHas('addresses',
                          function($q) use($country){
                            $q->where('idCountry','=',$country);
                          }
                        )
                      ->orWhereHas('institutes',
                        function($q) use($country){
                          $q->whereHas('addresses',
                            function($q) use($country){
                              $q->where('idCountry','=',$country);
                            });
                        }
                      );
             });
    }
```

Comment: DId you not make it static on purpose? Do I understand it right that I have to split my query call into two calls: `$users = User::fromCountry('DE'); ` and `$users = User::queryIsMaster($users)->paginate(20);` ?

Comment: no you just call `$users = User::fromCountry('DE')
                    ->isMaster()
                    ->paginate(20);`

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do. Laravel uses scope for stuff like this

```
User {

   public function scopeOfType($query, $orga)
    {
        switch ($orga) {
        case 1:
          return $query->where('modeIN','=','MT');

        case 2:
          return $query->where('modeICI','=','CMT');

        case 3:
          return $query->where('modeWHO','=','HMT');
      }
    }


}
```

Then call it like this.

```
User::ofType(1);
User::ofType(2);
User::ofType(3);
```

For more info check https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Laravel Scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#global-scopes) :)